# Specific version of pdftotext binary (old version of poppler-utils is not same version)?

Tags: pdftotext, xpdf

Been digging for ages and struggling to find the answer.

Have version 0.39 of a single binary `pdftotext` on our OSX dev systems (installed using `brew install poppler`. We cannot find other versions `brew search poppler` only has a single one. We are trying to find the source for this specific version (to compile on linux). For some reason a specific pdf file we have only works on this version (not the newer). (Tried other things like Ghostscript pdftk but layout just not working).

I have tried downloading poppler utils (https://poppler.freedesktop.org) but v0.39 of utils, when compiled, doesn’t give the compiled binary (just the wrapper script version).

does anyone know:

- how does versioning of pdftotext binary work? (same as poplar utils version?)
- anyone know where older versions of pdf could be cached/mirrored - only seem to find latest (3.04)?
- ideas to back

or am i missing something?

thanks in advance, appreciate if anyone has a steer 
ben

```
        $ which pdftotext
        /usr/local/bin/pdftotext

        $ /usr/local/bin/pdftotext -v
        pdftotext version 0.39.0
        Copyright 2005-2015 The Poppler Developers - http://poppler.freedesktop.org
        Copyright 1996-2011 Glyph & Cog, LLC

        $ uname
        Darwin
```

downloading poppler-0.39.0.tar.xz, ./configure & make only provides

```
         in /tmp/poppler-0.39.0/utils
        $ ls -lt | grep pdftotext
        -rwxr-xr-x  1 ben.forrest  wheel    6417  5 Sep 18:48 pdftotext

        -rw-r--r--@ 1 ben.forrest  wheel    3273  1 Sep  2015 pdftotext.1
          in /tmp/poppler-0.39.0/utils
        $ file pdftotext
        pdftotext: POSIX shell script text executable
```

brew install notes

```
    $ brew search poppler
    poppler ✔


     $ brew info poppler
    poppler: stable 0.39.0 (bottled)
    PDF rendering library (based on the xpdf-3.0 code base)
    http://poppler.freedesktop.org
    Conflicts with: pdftohtml
    /usr/local/Cellar/poppler/0.39.0 (473 files, 22.4M) *
      Poured from bottle
    From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/poppler.rb
    ==> Dependencies
    Build: xz ✔, pkg-config ✔
    Required: cairo ✔, fontconfig ✔, freetype ✔, gettext ✔, glib ✔, gobject-introspection ✔, jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, libtiff ✔, openjpeg ✔
    Optional: qt ✔, qt5 ✘, little-cms2 ✔
    ==> Options
    --with-little-cms2
        Use color management system
    --with-qt
        Build Qt backend
    --with-qt5
        Build Qt5 backend
```

Answer (score 3):

For those that may care, the older versions have a wrapper script that calls a compiled process. That compiled process is actually in a ".lib" directory which is why it wasn't showing on my Mac in finder, and only find on command line for another search I came across it. `#{popplerdir}/utils/.libs/pdftotext` . and thats the version I needed.